# Android regex pattern unclosed character error

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex:

```
String regexContact = "^([0|\\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$";
```

Android is pointing error at the end of the regex, saying:

> Unclosed character class.

I have sifted through similar questions but could not find an answer for this particular error in my case. I am unable to find out if my regex itself is wrong somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your first square bracket is not closed correctly.

Comment: What is the format of strings you want to match? I think you just need to remove the first `[` as it is just erroneous as it starts a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([0|\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$
 ^↑    ^___^     ^ ^^___^^___^   ^
 |_______________| |_____________|
```

This first `[` is not closed, if you want to match it literally, you should escape it: `\\[`, otherwise you should close it with a corresponding `]`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java regex flavor, the `[` and `]` symbols should be escaped inside a character class to denote literal symbols.

You have `[0|\\+[0-9]`, where a `[` is not escaped, and is considered a starting point for a character class, making the first `[` unpaired, hence the error.

You need to remove the first `[`

```
String pat = "^(0|\\+[0-9]{1,5})?([7-9][0-9]{9})$";
               ^^
```

so as to match:

- `^` - start of string
- `(0|\\+[0-9]{1,5})?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `0` - a zero
  - `|` - or
  - `\+[0-9]{1,5}` - a plus symbol and any 1 to 5 digits
- `([7-9][0-9]{9})` - Group 2 matching a `7`, `8` or `9` and then any nine digits (these parentheses here can be removed)
- `$`  - up to the end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH4iB6/1)